# iPhone - Quit Tab when Switching

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab based application with 3 tabs. How do I go about completely closing the view controller of a specific tab when it is switched? It should start again when it starts again.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you saying you just want all the data to be reinitialized when the user comes back to the view?  So user switches from A to B, and then does some stuff in B, and then goes back to A.  You want A to be refreshed like the app was just freshly loaded?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Just in the context of tabs and its containing viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is for your initialization code to run again when you switch back to that tab, move it to the `-viewWillAppear:` method. If you need to return things to a default state, you can do it in the `-viewWillDisappear:` method.